# Getting 'actionlink' is not a member of 'System.Web.WebPages.Html.HtmlHelper' message

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2013, asp.net-mvc-5, html-helper

I am getting this message when I try to type out an action link in a view. However the error is not there in _Layout.vbhtml in the Shared folder. I have updated to VS2013 Update 2.

Comment: No answer for this ?

Comment: I solved it but honestly don't remember how now.